# Synaptic Package Manager -E-"cache open", E - Default-Release not available

Tags: bash, package-management, software-sources

In an attempt to re-install Bash I tried to open Synaptic Package Manager but got this message

```
E: The value 'precise-updates' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Now every time I open synaptics package manager it gives me this error and closes. I can't re-install Bash using SPM.

I am running 14.04.1 so I am no sure why the "precise-updates" is still in my system.

How do I update the sources?

Comment: is `precise-updates` is present in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file ?

Comment: You should check https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+question/243301.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `/root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf`. You will find a line referring to `precise-updates`. Remove that and restart Synaptic.

I have opened a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1521672